# Два графика boxplot внутри одного

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, графики

Как отобразить два графика **boxplot** на одном графике.  Имеются два одинаковых по названию столбца, но в разных датасетах. Они в одном масштабе и с одинаковыми единицами измерения.

```
a=df_train['rougher.input.feed_size']
b=df_test['rougher.input.feed_size']
```

Необходимо сравнить их. Как построить два боксплота в seaborn, чтобы наглядно посмотреть разницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример [на английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384984/8324991) с использованием `plt.subplots`:

```py
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2) # можно ещё добавить параметр sharey=True

sns.boxplot(  y="b", x= "a", data=df,  orient='v' , ax=axes[0])
sns.boxplot(  y="c", x= "a", data=df,  orient='v' , ax=axes[1])
```

Вам немного нужно будет приспособить под себя, но, думаю, идея понятна.

Update: Конкретно для вашего случая попробуйте так:

```py
sns.boxplot(y="rougher.input.feed_size", data=df_train, orient='v', ax=axes[0])
sns.boxplot(y="rougher.input.feed_size", data=df_test, orient='v', ax=axes[1])
```

Comment: так тут один и тот же df. А у меня разные. Если просто вставить в X и Y то не получается.

Comment: Ну вы же можете и `data=` поменять. Я добавил вариант кода.

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо. Размер только мелковат, попробую исправить.

Comment: Параметр `figsize=` в `subplots` работает, я проверил, можете им задать размеры графика, хоть `(10,10)`, хоть сколько хотите.